# Why would a company issue a put warrant at this strike price?

Tags: warrants

On interactive brokers I was looking at stock warrants for BP. I saw a put warrant with a strike price of 600 GBP and its price was 5.12 EUR with commission.

Why would this warrant be issued? Isn't it an automatic loss for the issuer since the price of BP. is around 5.08 GBP a share.
The contract was: 
BP. MAR 15 '19 600 GBP Put (VON,1) @FWB

Comment: Does it make sense if the strike is 600 _pence_ (6 pounds)?

Comment: Yeah it would but wouldn't it be 600 GBX instead?

Comment: sometimes GBX is written as GBp (as opposed to GBP for pounds) which is infuriatingly good at creating misunderstandings like this. I suspect that this is a typo on IB caused by or related to that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose what the U.S. calls an exchange-traded put-option that Europe calls it a put-warrant.

The writer of the put-warrant receives a premium based on the strike-price, on the time length of the warrant, on the underlying stock price at the time of the write, and on other factors such as volatility. It's not known who writes a warrant but the investment bank making a market in the warrant could be known.

If the put-warrant were expiring this moment it would be priced at 6 - 5.09 or 0.91 . But since there is more than three months time left then the price of the warrant is more than 0.91 . (Or price with 600 - 508.7 = 91.3 GBX.)

I found a BP put-warrant with a strike of 6 and an expiration of 3/15/2019 currently trading at 1.10 euros in London. The issuer is Société Générale.

Comment: So is interactive brokers at fault for giving incorrect information?

Comment: Go to the option chain.

Comment: Warrants are slightly different than options (but prices similarly). The difference is that warrants are fulfilled by the company issuing more stock, not stock trading on the open market.

Comment: The subject concerns exchange-traded European put-warrants on BP that are issued by Societe Generale.